# JNDI does not work with HornetQ and tomcat

Tags: spring, tomcat, jms, jndi, hornetq

I'm trying running JMS application using hornetq on tomcat! I tried following [this article](http://wash-inside-out.blogspot.com/2010/08/hornetq-jms-integration-with-tomcat.html). I put jndi.properties in my client class path;  jndi.properties:

```
java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory 
java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.apache.naming
```

I added these dependencies to pom.xml:

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>tomcat</groupId> 
    <artifactId>naming-factory</artifactId> 
    <version>5.5.23</version> 
    <scope>test</scope> 
</dependency> 
<dependency> 
     <groupId>tomcat</groupId> 
     <artifactId>naming-resources</artifactId> 
     <version>5.5.23</version> 
     <scope>test</scope> 
 </dependency>
```

My JMS spring beans:

```
<bean id="jndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
        <property name="environment">
            <props>
                <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory</prop>
                <prop key="java.naming.factory.url.pkgs">org.apache.naming</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

<!-- Connection Factory -->
<bean id="hornetqConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiTemplate" ref="jndiTemplate"/>
    <property name="jndiName" value="/ConnectionFactory" />
</bean>

<!-- Destinations -->
<bean id="annotationDeleteCommandDestination" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiTemplate" ref="jndiTemplate"/>
    <property name="jndiName" value="/queue/command/annotation/deleteQueue" />
</bean>
```

I'm using HornetQ default server (standalone, non-clustered)

hornetq-jms.xml:

```
<queue name="annotationDeleteCommandQueue">
    <entry name="/queue/command/annotation/deleteQueue"/>
</queue>

<connection-factory name="NettyConnectionFactory">
      <xa>false</xa>
      <connectors>
         <connector-ref connector-name="netty"/>
      </connectors>
      <entries>
         <entry name="/ConnectionFactory"/>
      </entries>
   </connection-factory>
```

But when i starting tomcat i get this error:

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hornetqConnectionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/config/spring/applicationContext-jms.xml]: 
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name ConnectionFactory is not bound in this Context .........
```

What is wrong?
Should i put any jar files in the tomcat classpath? (which jars?)
Should i put queues and connection factories definitions in the tomcat configs? (how?)
Can i disable JNDI in tomcat and use hornetq standalone JNDI instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem by modification of jndiTemplate (using jboss naming) and adding jnp-client.jar to client classpath:

```
<bean id="jndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
    <property name="environment">
        <props>
            <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.factory.url.pkgs">org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">jnp://localhost:1099</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sur HornetQ is started correctly? The error log seems to indicate that the  `ConnectionFactory` is not present.

Have you tried to access HornetQ using another tool? 
You should be able to use JMX or HermesJMS (http://www.hermesjms.com) to verify the presence of your `ConnectionFactory`

Comment: Yes it started correctly! My application works fine without tomcat!

Comment: Could you be more specific about HornetQ and Tomcat? You're JNDI configuration seems to indicate that they are running in the same JVM, is that right?