# in the hornetq, the consumer is automatically invoked?

Tags: hornetq

I looked over all of examples in the hornetq, but I couldn't find the example that the consumer is automactically invoked whenever the message comess through the producer.

Please let me know about the example code or hint. 
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Use [DefaultMessageListenerContainer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/). You can register a listener to it and consume messages asynchronously.  Follow this link for more information about tuning MessageListenerContainer:  http://bsnyderblog.blogspot.se/2010/05/tuning-jms-message-consumption-in.html.

Hornetq dependecies you need (I used a standalone hornetq-2.3.0.CR2) (You also need some spring jars):

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- hornetq -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>netty</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hornetq</groupId>
        <artifactId>hornetq-jms-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.CR2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hornetq</groupId>
        <artifactId>hornetq-core-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.CR2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- hornetq -->
</dependencies>
```

The beans you should use in your applicationContext.xml (I didn't use jndi for getting ConnectionFactory and destinations; For this, you can follow [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13049736/jndi-does-not-work-with-hornetq-and-tomcat)):

```
<!-- It's ConnectionFactory to connect to hornetq. 5445 is hornetq acceptor port  -->
<bean name="connectionFactory" class="messaging.jms.CustomHornetQJMSConnectionFactory"> 
    <constructor-arg index="0" name="ha" value="false" />
    <constructor-arg index="1" name="commaSepratedServerUrls" value="127.0.0.1:5445" /> 
</bean>

<bean id="destinationParent" class="messaging.jms.JmsDestinationFactoryBean" abstract="true">
    <property name="pubSubDomain" value="false" /> <!-- default is queue -->
</bean>

<bean id="exampleDestination" parent="destinationParent">
    <property name="destinationName" value="example" /> <!-- queue name -->
</bean>

 <!-- MessageListener -->
<bean id="messageHandler" class="messaging.consumer.MessageHandler">
</bean>

<!-- MessageListenerContainer -->
    <bean id="paymentListenerContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
        <property name="destination"       ref="exampleDestination" />
        <property name="messageListener"   ref="messageHandler" />
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
        <property name="sessionTransacted" value="true" />
        <property name="concurrentConsumers"    value="1" />
        <property name="maxConcurrentConsumers" value="10" />
        <property name="idleConsumerLimit"      value="2" />
        <property name="idleTaskExecutionLimit" value="5" />
        <property name="receiveTimeout"         value="3000" />
    </bean>
```

CustomHornetQJMSConnectionFactory:

```
public class CustomHornetQJMSConnectionFactory extends org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQJMSConnectionFactory
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public CustomHornetQJMSConnectionFactory(boolean ha, String commaSepratedServerUrls)
    {
        super(ha, converToTransportConfigurations(commaSepratedServerUrls));
    }

    public static TransportConfiguration[] converToTransportConfigurations(String commaSepratedServerUrls)
    {   
        String [] serverUrls = commaSepratedServerUrls.split(",");
        TransportConfiguration[] transportconfigurations = new TransportConfiguration[serverUrls.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < serverUrls.length; i++)
        {
            String[] urlParts = serverUrls[i].split(":");
            HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
            map.put(TransportConstants.HOST_PROP_NAME, urlParts[0]);
            map.put(TransportConstants.PORT_PROP_NAME, urlParts[1]);
            transportconfigurations[i] = new TransportConfiguration(NettyConnectorFactory.class.getName(), map);
        }
        return transportconfigurations;
    }
}
```

JmsDestinationFactoryBean (Used in destinationParent bean):

```
public class JmsDestinationFactoryBean implements FactoryBean<Destination>
{
    private String destinationName;
    private boolean pubSubDomain = false;

    public void setDestinationName(String destinationName) {
        this.destinationName = destinationName;
    }

    public void setPubSubDomain(boolean pubSubDomain) {
        this.pubSubDomain = pubSubDomain;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getObjectType() 
    {
        return Destination.class;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSingleton() 
    {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Destination getObject() throws Exception 
    {
        if(pubSubDomain)
        {
            return HornetQJMSClient.createTopic(destinationName);
        }
        else
        {           
            return HornetQJMSClient.createQueue(destinationName);           
        }
    }
}
```

MessageHandler (Received messages go to onMessage method for process) (For simplicity, You can implement javax.jms.MessageListener instead of SessionAwareMessageListener):

```
public class MessageHandler implements org.springframework.jms.listener.SessionAwareMessageListener<Message>
{
@Override
public void onMessage(Message msg, Session session) throws JMSException 
{
    if(msg instanceof TextMessage)
    {
        System.out.println(((TextMessage)msg).getText());
        session.commit();
    }
    else
    {
        session.rollback(); // send message back to the queue
    }
}
```